# Efficient structure to get all prefixes of a string that match a previously defined set of strings

Tags: c++, string, match, prefix

Suppose that I have a set of prefixes such as ["a", "ab", "ba", "aba", "bbb"].

I also have a list of words. For each word in this list, for example "abad", I want to obtain efficiently all the prefixes of this word that match a word in the set of prefixes. In this example I would like as output ["a","ab", "aba"].

I want to only use structures from the std.

I am thinking about some kind of tree structure, but I can't think of a way of implementing it relatively effortlessly.

Comment: How about a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)?

Comment: that would be a perfect case for regular expressions from the std

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how can I implement a trie in a few lines of code using only std?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple implementation would be a hash table using std::unordered_set, and then compare each prefix of each word of the list with the set.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
    std::unordered_set<std::string> myPrefixes = {"a", "ab", "ba", "aba", "bbb"};

    std::vector<std::string> listOfWords;

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfWords.size(); i++) {
        std::vector<std::string> result;
        std::string word = listOfWords[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < word.length() - 1; j++) {
            if (myPrefixes.count(word.substr(0, word.length - j)) > 0) {
                result.push_back(word.substr(0, word.length - j);
            }
        }
        // print the result vector or do whatever with it
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick comment: you only need to search for up to the minimum length of the max lenght prefix or the word

Answer (score 1):

1. Store the prefixes in a `std::vector<std::string>`
2. `std::sort()` the vector
3. For each word of interest, use `std::mismatch()` to find the character they mismatch on, if all of the prefix is matched, then you have a match
4. If partial match, break

You don't need any special data structures. Will it be fast, probably not as fast as a trie, will it work - most likely. Is it efficient - could be - depending on prefixes and words.

Answer (score 1):

This answer adds a little complexity by using a trie for performance gain, which can be pretty huge. Assuming `M` prefix words, each along with words-to-search average `N` letters, the complexity of above procedure using `set` takes O(N^2) time to find prefixes of a `N` letter word. The Trie approach, for a initial O(MN) pre-processing cost, can bring the search down to O(N).

And interestingly, the Trie building part (`Node` struct and `insert` function below) actually takes just 7 real lines.

```
struct Node
{
    bool is_Leaf = false;
    unordered_map<char,Node*> transitions;
};

void insert(Node* node,char* str,char* end){
    if(str==end) {node->is_Leaf = true;return ;}
    if (node->transitions[*str]==nullptr) node->transitions[*str] = new Node();
    insert(node->transitions[*str],str+1,end);
}

void search(Node* root,char* str,char* end,string so_far=""){
    if(root && root->is_Leaf) cout<<so_far<<endl;
    if(!root or str==end) return;
    so_far.push_back(*str);
    search(root->transitions[*str],str+1,end,so_far); 
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Node* root = new Node();
    vector<string> prefixes = {"a", "ab", "ba", "aba", "bbb"};
    for(auto& s:prefixes) insert(root,&s[0],&s[0]+s.size());

    string to_search = "abad";
    search(root,&to_search[0],&to_search[0]+to_search.size(),"");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a trie is the fastes way. but i don't know if there is a std trie.
with a trie you are extremly fast in checking the prefixes.

your trie would look like this:

[image]

The red nodes are endnodes... so from top to a red node is a prefix.

if you only can use std things, you can write a class node. In this class you have a std::map to the children. if you have more than a's and b's in your trie, the map will help you to find the correct childnode fast... also if you use kanji or other alphabets... (with only a few elements you should better use a std::vector)

you also need a method to add prefixes.
afterwards you just need a method to check if the given word is a prefix by going throug the nodes and maps and check if we pass a red node.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned trie is a beginning for starting to look, some [Radix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) may be, however there are a lot of options, but, unfortunately, non of them is explicitly in std. If you want to have something quick and practical, I know [this article](http://igoro.com/archive/efficient-auto-complete-with-a-ternary-search-tree/) where it is described for C#, but it is easy doable in C++.